# Make MacMail display MY email address in full

Tags: macos

I have many different email addresses for work and home.

How do I make MacMail display MY full email address in emails where people have replied to me?

It's very annoying to have to click into each address to see which of my incoming mailboxes received the email.

This is not the same question as how to display recepients' full emails which can be done by unclicking SmartAddress.

Thank you.